# How to properly re-topo this mesh?

Tags: mesh, retopology

I am following some training about retopology. I understand why it is needed and the purpose. I am not looking for automatic retopology. I am practicing with a face, my problem is when linking meshes together (for example front to back, or around ears). I found some cue cards but they are from one side to another while in reality I need to link from multiple sides. Most times I end up with either triangles or pentagons and I am not sure  how to fix it.

Any advise is appreciated!!If you know of a good tutorial, please share it

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your title to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] it. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The important point is to know where to place loops and pole (vertex connected to more than 4 vertices) to have edge flow that works with the face

Here you have the edge loop:

[image]

Here you have area with pole:

[image]

Take a look at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C249AnzAI40&t=271s&ab_channel=GrantAbbitt
and this: https://polycount.com/discussion/80005/face-topology-breakdown-guide
You can always google "face edge flow" to get good reference picture

Answer (score 0):

If you remove one edge you can end up with this topology for example:

[image]